# Simplifying a pair of if-else statements around a Flask SqlAlchemy query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My query :

```
       if current_user['idx'] == 1:
            groups = sess.query(
            Role
            ).filter(
                ~Role.name.in_(codes.group1) # filtering
            ).order_by(
                Role.name
            )
        else:
            groups = sess.query(
            Role
            ).filter(
                ~Role.name.in_(codes.group2) # filtering
            ).order_by(
                Role.name
            )
```

My codes file :

```
group1= ['User']
group2 = ['Admin', 'User']
```

In my above query, I am filtering with `codes.group1` under the *`if`*-statement and with `codes.group2` under the *`else`*. As the querying part of the code looks repeated, is there any way to make the code more readable and clean without repetition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the queries are almost identical, you could do:

```
normal_user = current_user['idx'] == 1
groups = sess.query(
    Role
).filter(
    ~Role.name.in_(codes.group1 if normal_user else codes.group2)
).order_by(
    Role.name
)
```

or

```
group = codes.group1 if current_user['idx'] == 1 else codes.group2
groups = sess.query(
    Role
).filter(
    ~Role.name.in_(group)
).order_by(
    Role.name
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could build the query incrementally, like this:

```
groups = sess.query(Role)

if current_user['idx'] == 1:
    groups = groups.filter(~Role.name.in_(codes.group1))
else:
    groups = groups.filter(~Role.name.in_(codes.group2))

groups = groups.order_by(Role.name)
```

Comment: Thanks. Opening bracket of filter needs to be closed.